# how to search for elements containing unicode/arabic letters?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, unicode

I am running the below code to find an element containing Unicode Arabic characters. The below code works just fine if I replace XXX with English letter, however, if I replace them with Arabic letters It won't.

I checked the html page and it has "< meta charset="utf-8" >" so I set the character set in my Py script at the first line just to make sure the letters are interpreted as expected but still not working.

Any clue is much appreciate it.

Thanks

```
# coding=UTF8

from selenium import webdriver
# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("http://www.norikoptic.com/Product/Women")
print driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//*[contains(text(), 'XXX')]").text
```

Comment: Does this also not work for single arabic letters? Maybe there is confusion ablout right-to-left vs left-to-right text. Have you tried reversing the arabic-letters-part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not using the correct unicode in the xpath, 
check the demo in `Ipython` here

First I have selected one node to get the corresponding unicode for that arabic word, so after using that unicode modified the xpath as follows and this was the output.

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//li[@class="lensItem"]/a/text()').extract()
Out[1]: [u'\u0639\u062f\u0633\u06cc']

In [2]: response.xpath(u'//a[contains(text(), "\u0639\u062f\u0633\u06cc")]/text()').extract()
Out[2]:
[u'\u0639\u062f\u0633\u06cc',
 u'\u0639\u062f\u0633\u06cc',
 u'\u0645\u0634\u062e\u0635\u0627\u062a \u0639\u062f\u0633\u06cc \u0622\u0641\u062a\u0627\u0628\u06cc']

In [3]: a = response.xpath(u'//a[contains(text(), "\u0639\u062f\u0633\u06cc")]/text()').extract()

In [4]: for i in a:
    ...:     print i
    ...:
عدسی
عدسی
مشخصات عدسی آفتابی
```

**Edit**

I have tested the xpath using `Scrapy` but this will also work with `selenium`,

```
In [6]: driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'//a[contains(text(), "\u0639\u062f\u0633\u06cc")]').text
Out[6]: u'\u0639\u062f\u0633\u06cc'
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issues.

Comment: also couldn't find the demo...??!!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing Text to be checked in `contains` (Replacement of 'XXX') from external file system like property file, excel etc. It would work.

Whey there is 'u' before your xpath in the example you have given ?

Comment: Do you mean to use an input file and set the encoding to utf8? Can you be more specific? Also, u'lablabla..' stands for unicode('lablabla..').

Comment: If try to use relative xpath instead, I get the following error message as I try to read the text of the element.  
print driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//table[@class='table table-striped']/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]").text

'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>